# Relative font URLs in CSS cause 403s on S3

Tags: css, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am using presigned URLs with boto3 in order to 'protect' (or at least limit access) to content stored on S3 (I pass a relative path to a Django view, and then generate a absolute presigned URL to the storage location on S3, then pass this as a redirect to the client which then retrieves the expected file):

```
import boto3    

class ContentStreamView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):


    def get_redirect_url(self, **kwargs):
         ... relevant code below
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id=self.storage_details.access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=self.storage_details.secret_key,
                      config=Config(signature_version=self.storage_details.signature_version))

        # Key will equal the filepath to the content required.
        return s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            ExpiresIn=60,
            Params={
                'Bucket': self.storage_details.bucket_name,
                'Key': kwargs['filepath']
            }
        )

    ... passes the URL back to the client in the get method of the CBV

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        ...
        url = self.get_redirect_url(filepath=path)
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

I have my CORS on S3 bucket set up like the following at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have CORS setup with Django to allow all:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

As an example when the browser tries to access `https://myapp.com/streamer/some_folder/css/some_css_file.css` then the browser is redirected to (and gets the file as expected) to the presigned S3 url: `https://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some_folder/css/some_css_file.css?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=credentials%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180924T145056Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=signature`.

This works great, **BUT**, the relative URLs within the css file (for fonts and probably images) return 403s.

Relative URLs are defined (for example):

**some_css_file.css**

```
...
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir LT';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../Fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf');
} 
....
```

When the client tries to access `src: url('../Fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf');` the relative URLs in the file return 403s likely because the bucket is locked-down and it would require signing the URL to access these paths.

How can I work around this?

Comment: You can download this font before serve it...

Comment: I could but that wouldn't solve the problem. The css file would still try and reference the S3 location which it doesn't have access to.

Comment: If you have put invocation with your relative path like http:/// remove all an try to download your font localy and import it in your css file manually

Comment: These are collections of user uploaded media files (exploded .epub files), so I can't hardcode the imports as the file names, and includes/imports in the css will change from file to file.

Comment: what's is your relative path to font ?

Comment: `src: url('../Fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf');` for example. (The relative path on S3 from the css file is correct and the files are available at that relative location).

Comment: I may try to 'intercept' files of type .css and then modify relative urls within them with full pre-signed urls instead of redirecting the client to the file on S3. But I was hoping for an easier option...

Comment: Try invoque python manage.py collect static

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have anything to do with static files as these are user uploaded media files.

Comment: I just confirmed that this is purely a permisions / signing issue by temporarily making the `../Fonts/*` folder and content public. Then the 403's went away. Unfortunately, this isn't an option.

Comment: There's an open [django-storages issue](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/734) for this, and a corresponding [closed (wontfix) ticket on Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31642#ticket). It seems there are still only two options: either override django admin templates/css-files where necessary, or simply set public access on the affected files (on S3).

Comment: I guess this is not really limited to Django, as any usage of `url()` in CSS, with relative paths to private files on S3 (or similar service), would have the same problem, regardless of the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but while using google cloud storage. The solution for me was to set those specific files as public. Google cloud storage enables one to make data public in a bucket selectively, i.e per object level

for google cloud storage, i followed this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

The sad part is that i have to do this iteratively for every file that is linked to by a relative url within a css file. It is tiresome but will get the job done and maintain required privacy

here is a link to the solution in google cloud storage https://cloudworks.dukamneti.co.ke/fonts-failed-load-resource-google-cloud-storage/#contact

Comment: I wasn't able to do that for my example as the files needed to always be private.